# xlsxwriter Conditional Format based on Formula not working

Tags: python, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I want to format an entire row if the value in column A starts with specific words.

This code checks if cell A# equals 'Totals' and formats the entire row:

```
testformat = wb.add_format({'bg_color': '#D9D9D9', 'font_color': 'red'})
worksheet.conditional_format(0,0,10, 10, {"type": "formula","criteria": '=INDIRECT("A"&ROW())="Totals"',"format": testformat})
```

However here is my modified code to check if the cell value equals 'Totals' or starts with 'A1', 'A2', or 'A3'. returns an error when I try to open the file:

```
worksheet.conditional_format(0,0,10, 10, {"type": "formula","criteria": '=OR(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()),{"Totals","A1*","A2*","A3*"}))',"format": testformat})
```

I tested the formulas in Excel and they work fine (returning `TRUE`) but why is there a problem with the second formula.

Comment: Are you sure that formula works in a conditional format in Excel. When I try it Excel gives this alert: "You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges), array constants, or the LAMBDA function for Conditional Formatting criteria."

Comment: @jmcnamara Ah, I was only testing the formula, not if it worked as conditional formatting. Is there a better formula that would work given my use case?

Answer (score 1):

That formula isn't valid in an conditional format. Your would get a warning like this in Excel:

> **Alert**: You may not use reference operators (such as unions, intersections, and ranges), array constants, or the LAMBDA function for Conditional Formatting criteria.

There are probably several ways to get the conditional format you want but I would just break it into several overlapping simple conditional formats. Something like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('conditional_format.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Add a format. Green fill with dark green text.
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE',
                               'font_color': '#006100'})

# Some sample data.
data = [
    ["Total", 72, 38, 30, 75, 48, 75, 66, 84, 86],
    ["A1", 24, 1, 84, 54, 62, 60, 3, 26, 59],
    ["B1", 79, 97, 13, 85, 93, 93, 22, 5, 14],
    ["A2", 71, 40, 17, 18, 79, 90, 93, 29, 47],
    ["Total", 25, 33, 23, 67, 1, 59, 79, 47, 36],
    ["A13", 99, 20, 88, 29, 33, 38, 54, 54, 88],
    ["B1", 57, 88, 28, 10, 26, 37, 7, 41, 48],
    ["A31", 78, 1, 96, 26, 45, 47, 33, 96, 36],
    ["B1", 54, 81, 66, 81, 90, 80, 93, 12, 55],
    ["A21", 5, 46, 14, 71, 19, 66, 36, 41, 21],
]

# Write the sample data.
for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
    worksheet.write_row(row , 0, row_data)

# Add conditional formats to highlight rows.
worksheet.conditional_format(0, 0, 9, 9,
    {'type': 'formula',
     'criteria': '=$A1 = "Total"',
     'format': format1})

# Repeat this one for the A* variants.
worksheet.conditional_format(0, 0, 9, 9,
    {'type': 'formula',
     'criteria': '=LEFT($A1,2)="A1"',
     'format': format1})


workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]